# Get Elevation of XY points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, elevation, xy

I am working with ArcMap 10.3.  I have imported DEM files.  When I imported the files they had the extension of .DDF.

I would now like to be able to take a list of XY coordinates and, for lack of a better term, merge them with the DEM files so that I can get the elevation of any given point.

I imported XY Data and projected it with the NAD 1983 coordinate system.  But, I can't figure out how to "combine" the 2 layers to get the elevation of my XY points.  I can right click on the map and click "Identify..." and get the elevation, but that's about it.

Also, if there is a way to do this without the Spatial Analyst extension, that would be great.  I am supposed to have it on my license, but for whatever reason I don't and need to know if there is a way to do this without it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, although very similar.  And the other solution does not work for me as I don't have access to the 3D Analyst extension either.

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but if you have a license, have you [enabled the extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018900000002000000)?

Comment: Have a look at my solution by following link in @DanC comment

Answer (score 1):

If you do have the 3D Analyst extension, it should work this way:

1. Use the tool 'Interpolate Shape'. This will add a Z coordinate information to your points.
2. Use tool tool 'Add XY coordinates'; this will add the XY and also Z coordinates of each point into the attribute table of the shape.